# ¿Generar numero consecutivo de 10 digitos como 0000000001 y se autoincremente con Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Mi duda es como puedo conseguir generar un consecutivo desde 0000000001 e irlo autoincrementando, ya que normalmente seria sin los ceros adicionales.

Comment: usando [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) ? onda `echo str_pad($input, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: Esta pregunta al menos cómo está planteada no tiene que ver con Laravel sino con PHP en todo caso

Answer (score 0):

La parte en la que dices que lo necesitas autoincrementar...no se como lo querrás hacer (lo dices por algo de DB?). En función de eso, la respuesta podría cambiar, pero a falta de más información, creo que lo que pides se podría hacer así:

```
$numero = 12345; //tu numero
$numero_final = str_pad($numero, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // "0000012345"

Si lo necesitas autoincrementar, no tienes más que hacer:
$numero_final++; // 12346
$numero_final = str_pad($numero_final, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // "0000012346"
```

Comment: Hasta no tener clara la pregunta, no debes responder